# stuck at Eigen value problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a matrix P such that 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & a & b \\a & 0 &b \end{bmatrix}

If P has eigen values 0 and 3 , then to determine value of a and b ?

I have taken c as my third eigen value and formed two ewuations as

$a + b +1 = b +c $ using trace =sum of eigen values

And $2ab - a^{2} =0$

How do i proceed from here .Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $\lambda=0$ or $3$, set up two equations $det(A-\lambda I)=0$, one of which will also give you the result $2ab-a^2=0$. For example, let $\lambda=0$, then determinant of

\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & a & b \\a & 0 &b \end{bmatrix}

is $2ab-a^2$. Let $\lambda=3$, find the determinant of

\begin{bmatrix} -2 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & a-3 & b \\a & 0 &b-3 \end{bmatrix}

From the first one $2ab-a^2=0$, you get $a=0$ or $a=2b$. Plug these two alternatives into the other equation obtained by $\lambda=3$, you will get three sets of values for $a,b$.

Comment: Then i get c =2b +1 .how do i proceed

Comment: You don't need the other eigenvalue $c$ to solve it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: I edited my post. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 3):

The characteristic polynomial is
\begin{align}
p(X)&=\det\begin{bmatrix}
1-X&1&1\\
0&a-X&b\\
a&0&b-X
\end{bmatrix}
\\[2ex]
&=
(1-X)\det\begin{bmatrix}
a-X&b\\
0&b-X
\end{bmatrix}
+a\det\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\
a-X&b
\end{bmatrix}
\\[2ex]
&=(1-X)(a-X)(b-X)+a(b-a+X)
\end{align}

Plug in $p(0)=0$ and $p(3)=0$ and solve the system.

Comment: I get real and complex valus, which oneto take

Comment: @JessicaGtb I get $a=0$ and $b=3$, or $a=2b$ and $b^2-2b+3=0$. The second set has indeed complex solutions; if your $a$ and $b$ have to be real, these can't be considered.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use another eigenvalue. You simply need to calculate the determinant of (P-1x) knowing that it has to give 0 if x=0 and x=3. You obtain the system of the two equations 2ab-a^2=0 and 9a+6b-ab-a^2-18=0
You have three (a,b) couples of solutions:
- (0,3)
- (6,3)
- (2,1)

Answer (score 0):

If $a=0$ you can read the eigenvalue on the diagonal, so $b=3$ and the other eigenvalue is $1$.

If $a \neq 0$, then you get, reducing in row echelon form, that $a = 2b$ (because the rank of $P$ cannot be maximum)

Now to find $b$ you can find the characteristic polynomial of $P$ (which is now much easier to compute, as you don't have the term $ab$) or you can reduce to row echelon form the matrix $P - 3I$, again with the condition that there cannot be $3$ pivots.

Comment: So i reject a = 2b from second equation

Comment: @JessicaGtb I'm sorry, I edited